# iOS UICollectionViewCell resizable dashed border

Tags: uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionviewcell, calayer, cashapelayer

I have a UICollectionView where some of the cells should have a dashed border and some of them should have a solid border. Also, the cells can be of varying size depending on the content that is present in the data model.

The problem I am having is that I cannot get the dashed border to be the same size as the collection view cell and again, the cell size can change based on the content. But basically, the cell should either have a dashed border or a solid border. The solid border is easy to get to resize to the correct size.

Here is a picture of what it looks like right now. The dashed border is colored green just to make it easier to see.

[image: rendered view]

Here is the view hierarchy debug view. There are two dashed borders here because I have been experimenting. The green border is a sublayer on the UICollectionViewCell's root layer. The grey border is a sublayer of a separate view that is a subview of the collection view cell's contentView property.

[image: view debugger]

#### Code

##### Approach 1 - add a dedicated view with a sublayer

Here I am trying to add a UIView subclass that has a dashed border. Then, when I need to show the dashed border or hide the dashed border, I just set the `hidden` property of the view accordingly. This works fine, except I cannot get the dashed border sublayer to resize.

The view is resizing to be the correct width and height based on the AutoLayout constraints, as can be seen in the view hierarchy debugger screenshot above. But the sublayer is still the original size (approximately 50px x 50px, which I guess is coming from the UICollectionView because I am not specifying that size anywhere).

For this implementation, I have a custom UIView subclass called `MyResizableSublayerView`. It overrides `layoutSublayersOfLayer` to handle the resizing of the sublayer, or at least that is what is supposed to be happening, but clearly it is not working.

But then the `MyResizableSublayerView` class is used in the collection view cell to add the dashed border to the view hierarchy.

###### MyResizableSublayerView

```objectivec
@interface MyResizableSublayerView : UIView

@property (strong, nonatomic) CAShapeLayer *borderLayer;

+ (instancetype)viewWithBorderSublayer:(CAShapeLayer *)shapeLayer;

@end




@implementation MyResizableSublayerView

+ (instancetype)viewWithBorderSublayer:(CAShapeLayer *)shapeLayer {
    CIResizableSublayerView *view = [[MyResizableSublayerView alloc] init];
    view.borderLayer = shapeLayer;
    return view;
}

- (void)setBorderLayer:(CAShapeLayer *)borderLayer {
    if (self->_borderLayer) {
        [self->_borderLayer removeFromSuperlayer];
    }
    
    self->_borderLayer = borderLayer;
    [self.layer addSublayer:self->_borderLayer];
}

- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    [super layoutSublayersOfLayer:layer];
    self.borderLayer.frame = layer.bounds;
}


@end
```

###### MyCollectionViewCell

```objectivec
@interface MyCollectionViewCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) MyResizableSublayerView *unavailableBorderView;

@end



@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize {
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    //... add other subviews
    [self.contentView addSubview:self.unavailableBorderView];
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.contentView.widthAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant:250.0],
        [self.contentView.widthAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToConstant:100.0],
        
        [self.unavailableBorderView.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.leadingAnchor],
        [self.unavailableBorderView.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.topAnchor],
        [self.unavailableBorderView.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.trailingAnchor],
        [self.unavailableBorderView.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.contentView.bottomAnchor],
        
        //... constraints for other views
    ]];
}

- (MyResizableSublayerView *)unavailableBorderView {
    if (!self->_unavailableBorderView) {
        CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        layer.strokeColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0xE0/255.0 green:0xE0/255.0 blue:0xE0/255.0 alpha:1.0].CGColor;
        layer.lineWidth = 4.0;
        layer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
        layer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
        layer.lineDashPattern = @[@4, @4];
        layer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
        layer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.contentView.bounds cornerRadius:self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;

        self->_unavailableBorderView = [MyResizableSublayerView viewWithBorderSublayer:layer];
        self->_unavailableBorderView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self->_unavailableBorderView.layer.cornerRadius = self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius;
        self->_unavailableBorderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:1.0 alpha:0.0];
    }
    return self->_unavailableBorderView;
}

//... more logic

@end
```

##### Approach 2 - add directly to the UICollectionViewCell

For this approach, I add the CAShapeLayer directly to the UICollectionViewCell and then override the `layoutSublayersOfLayer` to try to resize the dashed border sublayer, but this is not working either.

```objectivec
@interface MyCollectionViewCell ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) CAShapeLayer *unavailableBorderLayer;

@end



@implementation MyCollectionViewCell

- (instancetype)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:coder]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self initialize];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)initialize {
    self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 4.0f;
    self.contentView.layer.borderWidth = 1.0f;

    //... add other subviews
    
    [NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [self.contentView.widthAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant:250.0],
        [self.contentView.widthAnchor constraintGreaterThanOrEqualToConstant:100.0],
        
        //... constraints for other views
    ]];
    
    
    CAShapeLayer *layer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    layer.strokeColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
    layer.lineWidth = 2.0;
    layer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinRound;
    layer.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    layer.lineDashPattern = @[@4, @4];
    layer.frame = self.contentView.bounds;
    layer.path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.contentView.bounds cornerRadius:self.contentView.layer.cornerRadius].CGPath;
    self->_unavailableBorderLayer = layer;
    [self.layer addSublayer:self->_unavailableBorderLayer];
}

- (void)layoutSublayersOfLayer:(CALayer *)layer {
    [super layoutSublayersOfLayer:layer];
    self.unavailableBorderLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}

//... more logic

@end
```

#### Questions

I have a couple of questions about this.

1. What is wrong with my code that is not allowing the dashed border to resize to be the same size as the collection view cell?
2. Which approach is the best approach to add a dashed border to the collection view cell. Or is there a better approach than the ones that I have listed here? Again my goal is to be able to show or hide the dashed border and for it to be the same size as the collection view cell, which is dynamically sized.

Comment: First, don't try modifying the content view's constraints: `[self.contentView.widthAnchor constraintLessThanOrEqualToConstant:250.0]` <- bad. Second, is there a reason you don't want to set the border style of the `contentView.layer`?

Comment: (1 of 2) @DonMag - Thanks for the reply. For the contentView constraints, those are there because I am wanting the collection view cell to have a min-width of 100 and a max-width of 250. Otherwise it can look really bad with some of the cells being very thin and some really wide. Is there a better way to set a min-widith and a max-width of the collection view cell? I noticed some AutoLayout unsatisfiable constraint errors because of some view has autoresizing masks turned on, which none of my views do, so it is probably the content view. Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: (2 of 2) @DonMag - For the second question about why the dashed border style is not directly on the main layer property of the view, it is just because I could not figure out a way to do that. It seems only CAShapeLayer has the dashed border properties, but the main `layer` property of a view is the more generic CALayer, which doesn't seem to support this. Is there a way to get the main layer on the view to have a dashed border without having to add a sublayer? Thank you again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not quite clear what you're doing with constraints on the content view ... however, if you are getting the layout you want, except for the dashed borders, give this a try.

First, instead of `layoutSublayersOfLayer`, use:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    _unavailableBorderLayer.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is working. I also had to update the path of the layer to be the correct width as well. As for the contentView constraints, all I am trying to do is to make sure the collection view cell is between 100px wide and 250px wide. Some of these cells may not have a lot of content, so the width can be really narrow. So I am just trying to make sure each cell is at least 100px wide but no wider than 250px. Is there a better way of doing this than applying the constraint on the contentView? Thanks so much again for your help.

Comment: @ashipma - as a general rule, use constraints on the UI elements added to the contentView to manage the sizing. Simple example: add a label, constrained Leading/Trailing to contentView, and give the **label** the width constraints.

Comment: Thanks so much. I will do that. That might fix the AutoLayout warning I am getting in the logs about unsatisfiable constraints. Plus, I have also seen occasionally, weird behavior where if I expand a row in the table, then the whole collection view might not show up (it will only show the top half of the items) or sometimes the collection view cells will appear on multiple lines (it should be a single line horizontal collection view). But those issues are not easily reproducible. Perhaps it is some AutoLayout issue and it might be related to this. Anyway, thank you so much.